# NullPointerException on getWritableDatabase()

Tags: android, getwritabledatabase

i have a problem NullPointerException on getWritableDatabase()

```
public class DatabaseTable extends Activity {
            private Context context;
            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                LBD conection = LBD.get(this);
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            }
        }
```

There is an implementation does not work "openHelper.getWritableDatabase()"

```
       public class LBD {
                    private Context context;
                    private static SQLiteDatabase db;
                    private OpenHelper openHelper;
                    public static LBD get(Context context) {
                        LBD lbd = new LBD(context);
                        lbd.open();
                        return lbd;
                    }
                    public LBD(Context c) {
                        context = c;
                    }
                    final public void open() {
                                openHelper = new OpenHelper(context);
                                db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();

                    }
                    public class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
                        OpenHelper(Context context) {
                            super(context, "rss_base.db", null, 3);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

[image]

[image]

**I realized, I forgot to initialize the onCreate Thanks to everyone**

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace and a little more of your code?

Comment: please post the code of the OpenHelper class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely your `Context`

```
openHelper = new OpenHelper(context);
```

is null. Make sure that your `Context` is set. But i recommend to you provide more details, add here your logcat.

Comment: This looks correct. The context passed in to the constructor should be saved, and passed into the OpenHelper method.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not in your Database Class, its at `DatabaseTable.onCreate()..... java:27`

Please check it out.

Thanks,

Haps.

Comment: public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 
  LBD conection = LBD.get(getApplicationContext());

Comment: Hi @MaxUsanin, dude, please add the complete code of these 2 Java Classes i.e. "Database Class" and this exception creating class "Database Table" in paste.org and give us the link for it. So we can easy understand the whole class and help you to remove ur bug.